# Raspberry Pi 3B Randomly Reboots After Kernel Upgrade

Tags: pi-3, linux, raspberry-pi-os

I have this strange behaviour from my raspberry pi;

I have Raspbian Jessie 4.9.35 installed on it and a reboot never occured, but as soon as I switch from that kernel version to a more recent one the Pi starts to randomly reboots without a reason.

I've checked the power supply with the oscilloscope and everything is fine on that side of things.

I've tried any possible thing but with no avail.

I can't understand what differs from one kernel version to another one.

SD Card is a kingston 8GB Industrial.

Comment: `switch from that kernel version to a more recent one` - how recent? how do you `switch` to the more recent kernel?

Comment: @JaromandaX By Switching I mean I install a fresh new image on it. For Example Raspbian Bullseye

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to be sure you're not doing something implausible :p